# Card View Vertical

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-cardview

I am having significant difficulty in this and have tried everything imaginable. I am trying to make a card view draggable/swipeable vertically. All I want to accomplish is for the user to be able to swipe/drag the card view up and down. Please see attached photos-this is what I am trying to accomplish.

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardviewbackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-175dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActicity.kt

```
class MainActivity<T> : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
    val listener = View.OnDragListener { view, event ->
        when(event.action) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                event.clipDescription.hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)

            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: check also: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Card.md#making-a-card-draggable

Comment: thanks for the help!